# Iterate Generic List of Strings (Lync chatroom members) in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, generic-list, lync

I can't iterate through a Generic List of Strings in Powershell. The Object is the members of a Lync chatroom. Command to get the Generic List:

```
$crMembers = get-csPersistentChatroom -identity "XXXX" | select members
```

The error I receive when trying to read the Strings in the Generic List is:

```
WARNING: An error ocurred: Cannot convert value 
"@{Members=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]}" to type 
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]". Error: "Cannot convert the 
"@{Members=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]}" value of type 
"Selected.Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Chat.Cmdlets.ChatRoom" to type 
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"."
```

I have also tried this without success:

```
foreach ($Member in $crMembers.GetEnumerator())
{
    Write-Host $Member
}
```

How can I iterate a **"@{Members=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]}"** without errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list is a property of the $crMembers object, called "Members", so

```
Foreach ($Member in $crMembers.Members)
 {...}
```