# powershell System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String] and foreach

Tags: list, powershell, foreach

I'm finding that I have the following Generic List, and I can see it has items in it, but when I try to run the code, it's not hitting inside the foreach.  This is my code:

```
function SQLQueryWriteToFile([string]$SQLquery, [string]$extractFile)
{

   $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

   $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=blah;Database=blah;User ID=blah;Password=blah"  #production #I have an error in this so it doesn't connect
      $sqlConnection.Open()
   if($sqlConnection.State -ne 'Open'){
      $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Exception: $("Couldn't connect to DB with connection string given");;  ") #this gets hit
   }

###

$global:ErrorStrings = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String] #System.Object]
$query = "Select blah"
$dir = "C:\blah"

SQLQueryWriteToFile $query $dir

$errorCodeAsString = ""

foreach ($item in $global:ErrorStrings.Members){
   $errorCodeAsString += $item  #this isn't hit
}
```

Any idea why it's not finding the error string in my list for the foreach loop, when I can see it's in there looking at $global:ErrorStrings?  Based on this [foreach list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099674/iterate-generic-list-of-strings-lync-chatroom-members-in-powershell), I'm doing it correctly.  I'm having trouble finding examples like what I'm doing.  Thanks!

Comment: as shown you create the list but never add anything to it.

Comment: It adds to the list when it fails opening the DB connection at this line: $global:ErrorStrings.Add("Exception: $("Couldn't connect to DB with connection string

Comment: i cannot find a `.Members` property for a generic.list ... where is `$global:ErrorStrings.Members` coming from?

Comment: I got it from the example at my link.

Comment: I got rid of .Members in the foreach and it seemed to work.

Comment: @Michele - glad to hear that you fixed it! [*grin*] ///// next time something seems off ... try looking at the output of the $Var involved. you would have either received an error OR a blank when trying to use `.Members` in that situation. it's one of the truly nifty things about working in an interpreted setup ... you can explore the items interactively! [*grin*]

Comment: @Michele: As your specific problem is unlikely to be of general interest to future readers, can I suggest you delete your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function SQLQueryWriteToFile([string]$SQLquery, [string]$extractFile)
{
  [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection] $sqlConnection=$null
  [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand] $command=$null 
  try
  {
      $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
      $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=blah;Database=blah;User ID=blah;Password=blah"
      $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
      $command.Connection=$sqlConnection
      $command.CommandText=$SQLquery

      $sqlConnection.Open()
      $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

  }
  catch
  {
      $global:ErrorStrings.Add($_.Exception.Message)
  }
  finally
  {
      if ($sqlConnection -ne $null) 
      {
        $sqlConnection.Close()
        $sqlConnection.Dispose()
      }

      if ($command -ne $null) 
      {
        $command.Dispose()
      }
  }

}


$global:ErrorStrings = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
$query = "Select blah"
$dir = "C:\blah"

$global:ErrorStrings.Clear()
SQLQueryWriteToFile $query $dir

$errorCodeAsString=""

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $global:ErrorStrings.Count; $i++)
{ 
    $errorCodeAsString +=$global:ErrorStrings.Item($i)
}

$errorCodeAsString
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Esperento57! I couldn't executeNonQuery since it's not an update, etc, but it caught the exception of the wrong login.  Also, the for loop works.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy for you :) Yes i have use executenonquery but you can use executequery and dataset like usually, it was for complet example . have a good day